# What's the right way to restore using SQL Azure point in time restore?

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup

This afternoon a Sitefinity application broke. Our client had been madly updating content in preparation for imminent go live. We quickly decided that restoring the SQL Azure database would be the fastest way to fix things.

Something I had done in the last 10-20 minutes broke the application. The client had been updating content during this time. To avoid losing too many content updates, I thought I would try restoring to 10 minutes prior, then if that didn't work, try 20 minutes.

I used the Azure portal to restore to a new database from 10 minutes prior. This finished in about 5 minutes. I stopped the application, renamed the original database _latest, then renamed the restored database to the original name, then restarted the app.

Unfortunately the problem was still present, so I thought I would then try restoring to 20 minutes prior.

The problem is, after I have renamed the databases, all the point in time restore data is gone - from both the original and the restored!

I tried renaming the _latest database back to it's original name, but still there is NO restore data available!

So, I'm wondering what procedure should I follow to restore a database without losing the restore data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize this happened.

In the future the best way to test this out is to restore the database to a different name but keep the original name with the original database.

Renaming causes a few different operations to run in the background to make the rename happen and I know at least one of those will break the backup chain.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty bad. Will this be fixed with the new portal?

Comment: OK, as far as I can tell, this has been fixed in the meantime. I just renamed an Azure SQL database using SSMS and the name change has been reflected in the portal and the renamed database kept its restore data